# Recover MongoDB data from inaccessible replica set

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-replica-set, mongodb-cluster

I had previously created a 3-node docker cluster of MongoDB with port `27017` mapped to that of respective hosts.

I had then created a replica set `rs0` with it's members being `host1.mydomain.com:27017`, `host2.mydomain.com:27017` and `host3.mydomain.com:27017`. Please note that while creating the replica set, I had specified members with their `mydomain.com` addresses and not with `${IP1}:27017`, etc. I had the respective DNS records set up for each host.

Thus, I could connect to this cluster with string:

`mongodb+srv://admin:<pass>@host1.mydomain.com,host2.mydomain.com,host3.mydomain/admin?replicaSet=rs0`

Unfortunately, I have lost access to `mydomain.com` as it has expired and has been scooped up by another buyer.

I can still SSH into individual hosts and log into docker containers, type `mongo`, then `use admin;` and then successfully authenticate using `db.auth(<user>, <pass>)`. However, I cannot connect to the replica set nor can export the data out of it.

Here's what I get if I try to SSH into one of the nodes and try to access the data:

```bash
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v3.6.8
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("fc3cf772-b437-47ab-8faf-5e0d16158ff0") }
MongoDB server version: 4.4.10

> use admin;
switched to db admin

> db.auth('admin', <pass>)
1

> show dbs;
2022-07-22T13:37:38.013+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases failed:{
    "topologyVersion" : {
        "processId" : ObjectId("62da79de34490970182aacee"),
        "counter" : NumberLong(1)
    },
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not master and slaveOk=false",
    "code" : 13435,
    "codeName" : "NotPrimaryNoSecondaryOk"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:67:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:860:19
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:750:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1

> rs.slaveOk();

> show dbs;
2022-07-22T13:38:04.016+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: listDatabases failed:{
    "topologyVersion" : {
        "processId" : ObjectId("62da79de34490970182aacee"),
        "counter" : NumberLong(1)
    },
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "node is not in primary or recovering state",
    "code" : 13436,
    "codeName" : "NotPrimaryOrSecondary"
} :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
Mongo.prototype.getDBs@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:67:1
shellHelper.show@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:860:19
shellHelper@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:750:15
@(shellhelp2):1:1
```

How do I go about this? The DB contains important data that I would like to export or simply have the cluster (or one of the mongo hosts) running again.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to connect to replicaset to retrieve the data. All nodes keep a copy of the whole database. Connect to any standalone member and export data.

Comment: @AlexBlex: I have added output. I am unable to access any DBs other than admin. Thanks!

Comment: `rs.secondaryOk()`, but frankly, if the domain name resolution is the only problem - just add them to the `hosts` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following records to `/etc/hosts` file on each container running mongodb, and the client where you are connecting from:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  host1.mydomain.com
yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy  host2.mydomain.com
zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz  host3.mydomain.com
```

replace xxx, yyy, zzz with actual IP addresses that listen on 27017.

If the client is Windows, the hosts file is located at `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`

If the replica set restores, you will be able to connect to the database without +srv schema:

```
mongodb://admin:<pass>@host1.mydomain.com,host2.mydomain.com,host3.mydomain.com \
?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0
```

If you don't know network configuration, or the replica set did not recover for any reason, you still can connect to individual node as standalone instances.

Restart the mongodb without `--replSet` parameter in the command line (somewhere in your Dockerfile) or `replication` part in mongodb.conf. It will resolve the "NotPrimaryOrSecondary" error.

Comment: I added `127.0.0.1 host1.mydomain.com` in the `/etc/hosts` of the host as well as inside the `mongo:4.4` docker container running on the host. No avail.

Comment: However, I was able to restart the `mongo:4.4` Docker container without `--replSet` option as you suggested and access the DB and collections in it. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped. For the sake of other readers, the IP address in the hosts file must be the public IP, as it used to be registered on the nameserver, not the local loopback to 127.0.0.1  Think about /etc/hosts as your local nameserver. The OS queries a public DNS only if it cannot resolve domain name to an IP address from the local hosts file.